# How can I replace specific characters in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi in the log window I have two array.First one is my colored one as you can see the simulator blue ones.I want to change/replace blue ones with the second array but they are my chords .

[image: Screenshot]

Actually I tried like in following codes but all blue text changed with "Dbm" that was the second array's first string.

```
for txt in coloredTexts {

    for transposed in transposedAkorArray{
        
        self.akor_goster.text = self.akor_goster.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(txt)", with: "\(transposed)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Add the arrays as code instead of the screenshot.

Comment: The program works according to the logic written in the code. What is the problem?

Comment: Don't you want to keep the colors? If it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796827/detecting-different-colored-text-in-uitextview-in-swift/63797349#63797349 with another account, you could modify the content INSIDE the closure. You could check the value of the text, and call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1417045-replacecharacters

Comment: I fixed my problem but still thanks to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
for (index,txt) in coloredTexts.enumerated() {
    let range = akor_goster.text.range(of: txt)
    akor_goster.text.replacingOccurrences(of: txt, with: transposedAkorArray[index], options: [], range: range)
}
```

Comment: Great. Do accept(tick on left) if the answer helped. Happy Coding 

Comment: happy coding to you too :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
for i in 0..<coloredTexts.count {
    self.akor_goster.text = self.akor_goster.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(coloredTexts[i])", with: "\(transposedAkorArray[i])")
}
```